# React Axios PUT authentication asks for infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, axios

For GET request the authentication working well, but when I am trying an authentication on PUT and POST requests it asks the USERNAME and PASSWORD for infinite times.
I written an authentication code for both GET and PUT but I am unable to understand why it s happening.
Please help me.

Here my GET request code:

```
var session_url = '';
var username = '';
var password = '';
var basicAuth = 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password);
axios.get(session_url, {}, {
  headers: { 
    "Authorization": + basicAuth,
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
   }
}).then((getData) => {
    console.log(getData.data);
    setApiData(getData.data);
}).then(function(response) {
  console.log('Authenticated');
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log('Error on Authentication');
});
```

Here my PUT request code:

```
var session_url = '';
var username = '';
var password = '';
var basicAuth = 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password);
axios.put(session_url, {}, {
  headers: { 
    "Authorization": + basicAuth,
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
   },
  "parameters":{
    "Name":name,
    "Email":email
  }
}).then(function(response) {
  console.log('Authenticated');
  alert("success");
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log('Error on Authentication');
});
```

"parameters" is the data in my json file.

Here my json file formate fetching from the API (This not an actual data, its just a formate of a json data)

```
[{"parameters":{"Name":"abc","Email":"abc@gmail.com"}}]
```

Comment: Can you also post the backend code? Seems like a problem with backend

Comment: I am not doing anything in the backend. I am just using API calls in React for fetching the data and trying to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

We have to pass body value in data parameters. Please try it.

```
axios.put(session_url, {}, {
  headers: { 
    "Authorization": + basicAuth,
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
   },
  data:{
     Name:name,
     Email:email
   },
})
```

for more reference check this https://stackabuse.com/how-to-make-put-http-request-with-axios/

Comment: I tried your solution but still it is asking a username and password in an infinite loop.